# Как обработать отмену установки пакета?

Tags: android

Программно запускаю установку приложения:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() 
   + "/download/" + "main.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Как отследить событие отмены установки пользователем? 
Как отследить если пользователь согласился на установку приложения, но после установки не запустил его по запросу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запускайте `startActivityForResult()` и ловите `onActivityResult()`

[Документация](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent))

Comment: С Наступающим и чтобы `onActivityResult()` всегда возвращал `RESULT_OK`!